# noun clause & attributive clause

Tags: grammar

Can “attributive clause” and “noun clause” be exchanged, excluding appositive clause?

For example:

> 1. Remind the clients what maintenance advice they should follow.(object clause)
> 2. Remind the clients the maintenance advice that they should follow.
> 3. I wonder where she comes from. (object clause)
> 4. I wonder the place that she comes from.
> 5. Whoever says that is a liar.(subject clause)
> 6. Anyone who says that is a liar.
> 7. That is what he meant.(predicative clause)
> 8. That is the meaning that he meant.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remind the clients what maintenance advice they should follow.(object clause)

Remind the clients *of* the maintenance advice that they should follow.

I wonder where she comes from. (object clause)

I wonder *about* the place that she comes from. (this one could be wrong, I think it might have to remain the object clause)

Whoever says that is a liar.(subject clause)

Anyone who says that is a liar. - this one is fine

That is what he meant.(predicative clause)

That is the meaning that he meant. - this one is also correct